# Bulk SMS APP in Android Studio with Oracle Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sms

I am a beginner and I am creating an bulk SMS sending app using SQLite database. I did this code to send message and now I want that when a message sent correctly without any error then this message record is deleted from SQLite database list but issue is this that SMS is not sent due to not having enough balance but record deleted from SQLite. Below mention is my code. One more thing I am fetching data from oracle to SQLite and then perform SMS message sending process. Waiting for your kind response. Thanks

**MainActivity**

```
    private void init() {
        model = new ArrayList<>();
        sync = findViewById(R.id.send);
        settings = findViewById(R.id.settings);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
//        viewBtn = findViewById(R.id.view);
        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    }

    private void checkdb() {
        model = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this).GetContacts();
        if (model != null && model.size() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "db have data now sending sms!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendIt();
        } else {
            getData();
        }
    }

    //Retrieve data from Oracle Database into sqlite Database

    private void getData() {

        MyInterfaces myInterfaces = ApiClient.getClient().create(MyInterfaces.class);
        myInterfaces.fetchAnyLinkData("http://"+ip+"/test/connect.php").enqueue(new Callback<BasicApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicApiResponse> Call, Response<BasicApiResponse> response) {
                List<FetchData> basicApiResponse = response.body().getFetchData();
                if (basicApiResponse != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < basicApiResponse.size(); i++) {
                        FetchData data = basicApiResponse.get(i);
                        id = data.SMS_ID;
                        boolean insert = myDb.insertData(data.SMS_ID, data.SMS_TYPE_ID, data.MOBILE_NO, data.MSG, data.DATED, data.SMS_STATUS, data.COMMENTS);
                        if (insert) {
                            updateStatus();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("error", "Error");
                        }
                    }
                    sendIt();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database don't have data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasicApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(smsSentReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //The deliveredPI PendingIntent does not fire in the Android emulator.
        //You have to test the application on a real device to view it.
        //However, the sentPI PendingIntent works on both, the emulator as well as on a real device.

        smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Send Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    //Something went wrong and there's no way to tell what, why or how.
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    //Your device simply has no cell reception. You're probably in the middle of
                    //nowhere, somewhere inside, underground, or up in space.
                    //Certainly away from any cell phone tower.
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No service!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    //Something went wrong in the SMS stack, while doing something with a protocol
                    //description unit (PDU) (most likely putting it together for transmission).
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                switch(getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

            }
        };

        //register the BroadCastReceivers to listen for a specific broadcast
        //if they "hear" that broadcast, it will activate their onReceive() method
        registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    }





    private void sendIt() {
        Cursor cursor = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this).getAllData();
        cursor.moveToNext();
        for (int c = 0; c < cursor.getCount(); c++) {

            Model object = new Model(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
            model.add(object);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < model.size(); j++) {
            Log.i("For Loop", String.valueOf(j));

//                if (j % limit != 0 && j > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((pause * 1000));
                        Log.i("SMS Sent:", "SUCCESS");
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(model.get(j).MOBILE_NO, null, model.get(j).MSG, sentPI, null);
                        smsCount = smsCount + 1;
                        Toast.makeText(this, smsCount+" SMS Sent Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
//        }
        delete();
        sync.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void finalupdate(String smsId) {
        int fvalue = 0;
        MyInterfaces myInterfaces = ApiClient.getClient().create(MyInterfaces.class);
        myInterfaces.updatevalue(fvalue, smsId).enqueue(new Callback<BasicApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicApiResponse> call, Response<BasicApiResponse> response) {

                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (response.body().isError()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + response.body().isError_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + response.body().isError_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<BasicApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateStatus() {
        int value = 2;
        String smsId = id;
        MyInterfaces myInterfaces = ApiClient.getClient().create(MyInterfaces.class);
        myInterfaces.updatevalue(value, smsId).enqueue(new Callback<BasicApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicApiResponse> call, Response<BasicApiResponse> response) {

                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (response.body().isError()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + response.body().isError_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + response.body().isError_msg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<BasicApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }




    private void delete() {

        for (int k = 0; k < model.size(); k++) {
            finalupdate(model.get(k).getSMS_ID());
            Integer delete = myDb.delete(model.get(k).SMS_ID);
            if (delete > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In general, it's easier to get good answers to tightly scoped questions - in this case, I can't tell whether you have problems from Oracle to SQLite, deleting from SQLite, or getting an error from SMS sending. Do you think you can edit your question to focus it better?

Comment: Basically i want to do error handling like if there is no balance in my cell phone then sms will not sent and also not delete from SQLite database...